# How to set max date in date picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am trying to set max date in date picker getting error this

I am using this date picker
https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-calendar-react

```
render() {
    return (
      <DateInput
        name="date"
        placeholder="Date"
        // this works
        // maxDate={moment()}
       // this is not working
        maxDate={moment().subtract(1,'years')}
        value={this.state.date}
        iconPosition="left"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
```

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-v9v03

I am trying to **set max date 1 year before**

Comment: check it man.. follow this  https://jsfiddle.net/raj53/op8v0yaf/

Comment: @chandukomati that is jquery, not what the OP is looking for

Comment: the current selected from date it will be add 3 months min `TODate` set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an `initialDate` inside [minDate, maxDate] interval.

```
<DateInput
  maxDate={moment().subtract(1, "years")}
  initialDate={moment().subtract(1, "years")} <==
  value={this.state.date}
/>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-j4hbo)

[Source](https://github.com/arfedulov/semantic-ui-calendar-react/issues/127) (not sure why this isn't mentioned on their documentation).

Answer (score 1):

```
new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-365))
```

This line will return the date from exactly 365 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hello please below example:

import React from "react";

import { DateInput } from "semantic-ui-calendar-react";

const currentdate = new Date();
const currentYear = currentdate.getFullYear();
const maxdate = new Date(currentdate.setYear(currentdate.getFullYear() + 1));
class DateTimeForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      date: "",
      time: "",
      dateTime: "",
      datesRange: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event, { name, value }) => {
    if (this.state.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DateInput
        dateFormat="DD - MM - YYYY"
        name="date"
        placeholder="Date"
        maxDate={maxdate}
        value={this.state.date}
        iconPosition="left"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default DateTimeForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert using momment.js but according the docs: https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/mutability/

maybe you need to use `.format()`. I've added it in your codesanbox and it doesn't crash

Answer (score -1):

To get date after one month you can use this

```
 const currentDate = new Date()
  const calculateValidDate = new Date(currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1))
```